# Python.h file not found wile compiling with ninja

Tags: compiler-errors, ninja

I'm trying to compile mitsuba2 on Opensuse, the compiling with cmake went well, but then I hade to compile it with ninja and the message `Python.h file not found` comes out. I installed python3-dev, python3-devel but the problem still comes out.
What should I do?